# Exporting text object coordinates in DWG file to excel

Tags: excel, autocad, dwg

How can I export the coordinates of each of the text objects in the layers
`MovePLOTNUM` and `PLOTSNUM` to excel sheet (columns: layer, text value of the object, x, y). Is this possible with AutoCAD or I need another software? [here is the file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwMirpbclFbreDFabE9QbFpfR2s/view?usp=sharing) I tried to search the web to figure out how is this possible and could not find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FME Desktop you can do this in one transformer called [CoordinateExtractor](https://www.safe.com/transformers/coordinate-extractor/)

Here is your file with the MovePLOTNUM and PLTSNUM convert to csv.

Using FME 2016.1
[image]

_x and _y are your coordinates _z can be dropped as you do not have 3d coordinates.

For the AutoCAD Text String you need to add the [AttributeExposer](https://www.safe.com/transformers/attribute-exposer/)

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get also the text value of each object along with its coordinates.

Comment: yes using the Attribute Exposer Transformer - updated post with another image.

Comment: I downloaded the software, followed the diagram you posted and it worked. This is exactly what I am looking for. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the .DWG as a .DXF and then parse it into a .CSV with a number of languages or even manually do it with Notepad++ or other text editors.

OR a quick google search for 'convert dxf to csv' gave [this link](https://www.gisconvert.com/) which takes in a variety of formats including .DWG and .DXF.

Comment: I am now converting the file to `.CSV`